# How to return item to context menu in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

In my Android Studio, when I have a cursor on the regular exprssion and if I click Alt + Enter I see a context menu like this

[image]

There was an item `Check Regexp` or something like this but I click accidentaly `Disable...` and it disappeared. Tell me please where can I find it in android studio to make it return back.

Answer (score 0):

Those menu items are called `Intention Actions`.

> To configure intention settings using the Settings/Preferences dialog
>
> - Open the Settings / Preferences Dialog by pressing Ctrl+Alt+S or by choosing File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for macOS, and click Intentions under Editor.
> - In the Intentions page, clear the checkboxes of the intention actions or action c1ategories that you do not currently need.
>     Selecting or clearing a category affects all intention actions in this category.
> - Apply changes and close the dialog.

Check for details [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-intention-actions.html)